# Powerpoint Toggle button Compile error: expression expected

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to make a toggle button change its caption to true or false depending on whether it's true or false. I keep getting an error saying "Compile error: expression expected." Heres the code I'm using.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click() 
If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then 
    ToggleButton1.Caption = "Pressed" 
Else 
    ToggleButton1.Caption = "Not Pressed" 
End If 
End Sub
```

It takes me to Module 1 and highlights a < symbol.

Comment: "highlights a < symbol" ... I dont' see any < symbol in your code snippet.  Please show the line the compiler highlights (and surrounding code ideally)

Comment: I cannot give you the code. I have tried a new method to put it this project. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Is the toggle button added to the slide or on a userform?